# implementing REST sdk for custom platform

Tags: json, rest, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am implementing paypal REST integration for a new platform

I got stuck and would apprecıate any help

The interesting problem I get is the REST request I copied from the documentation page gives error. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/payments/

I am not using command line but a little windows app to send web requests.

I just used exact same payload and got this error

The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","information_link":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"c4a8716d8a791"}

The C# sample from the github works and when I use th json it generated everything works ok.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if I change the cardnumber the sample works. Will let paypal team now.